# Realm - multiple operations on the same object. Does my implementation hit the performance?

Tags: java, android, performance, realm

I need to check some data, whether or not to send a tracking info. This data is saved inside the Realm database. Here is the model:

```
public class RealmTrackedState extends RealmObject {

     @PrimaryKey
     private int id = 1;

     private RealmList<RealmChat> realmChatsStarted;
     private boolean isSupportChatOpened;
     private boolean isSupportChatAnswered;

      /* getters and setters */

}
```

The idea is - every chat that is not inside the `realmChatsStarted` should be tracked and then added to this list. Similar thing for `isSupportChatOpened` boolean - however because of the business logic this is a special case.

So - I've wrapped this inside one Realm object. And I've wrapped this into few `shouldTrack()` methods, like this:

```
@Override
public void insertOrUpdateAsync(@NonNull final RealmModel object, @Nullable OnInsertListener listener) {
    Realm instance = getRealmInstance();
    instance.executeTransactionAsync(realm -> realm.insertOrUpdate(object), () ->
                    notifyOnSuccessNclose(listener, instance),
            error -> notifyOnErrorNclose(listener, error, instance));
}

@Override
public RealmTrackedState getRealmTrackedState() {

    try (Realm instance = getRealmInstance()) {
        RealmResults<RealmTrackedState> trackedStates = instance.where(RealmTrackedState.class).findAll();

        if (!trackedStates.isEmpty()) {
            return instance.copyFromRealm(trackedStates.first());
        }
        RealmTrackedState trackedState = new RealmTrackedState();
        trackedState.setRealmChatsStarted(new RealmList<>());

        insertOrUpdateAsync(trackedState, null);

        return trackedState;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean shouldTrackChatStarted(@NonNull RealmChat chat) {
    if (getCurrentUser().isRecruiter()) {
        return false;
    }

    RealmList<RealmChat> channels = getRealmTrackedState().getRealmChatsStarted();

    for (RealmChat trackedChats : channels) {
        if (trackedChats.getId() == chat.getId()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    getRealmInstance().executeTransaction(realm -> {
        RealmTrackedState realmTrackedState = getRealmTrackedState();
        realmTrackedState.addChatStartedChat(chat);
        realm.insertOrUpdate(realmTrackedState);
    });

    return true;
}
```

And for any other field inside RealmTrackedState model happens the same. 
So, within the presenter class, where I'm firing a track I have this:

```
private void trackState(){
    if(dataManager.shouldTrackChatStarted(chatCache)){
        //track data
    }

    if(dataManager.shouldTrackSupportChatOpened(chatCache)){
        //track data
    }

    if(dataManager.shouldTrackWhatever(chatCache)){
        //track data
    }

    ...

}
```

And I wonder:
a. How much of a performance impact this would have.
I'm new to Realm, but for me opening and closing a DB looks ... heavy. 
I like in this implementation that each `should(...)` method is standalone. Even though I'm launching three of them in a row - in other cases I'd probably use only one. 
However would it be wiser to get this main object once and then operate on it? Sounds like it.

b. I see that I can either operate on synchronous and asynchronous transactions. I'm afraid that stacking a series of synchronous transactions may clog the CPU, and using the series of asynchronous may cause unexpected behaviour.

c. `@PrimaryKey` - I used this because of the wild copy paste session. Assuming that this class should have only instance - is it a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ad a.

Realm caches instances so opening and closing instances are not that expensive as it sounds. First time an app is opening a Realm file, a number of consistency checks are performed (primarily does model classes match classes on disk) but next time you open an instance, you don't do this check.

ad b.

If your transactions depend on each other, you might have to be careful. On the other hand, why have multiple transactions? An async transaction will notify you when it has completed which can help me to get the behaviour you except.

ad c.

Primary keys are useful when you update objects (using `insertOrUpdate()`) as the value is use to decide if you are creating/inserting or updating an object.